# Can't get derived WebDuino class to work - compile errors with 'Web_HelloWorld.ino'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, subclass, derived-class

I made a derived class called `WebServer_My2KNJ.h` of a working class called `WebServer_My2.h` (see Note section below for details on these files) and I got the following error when I tried compiling the example program: `Web_HelloWorld.ino`:

The compile Error message: (or see the attached file 'ErrorMsg.txt'):

```
Web_HelloWorld.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Web_HelloWorld:57: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(WebServer_My2KNJ&, WebServer_My2::ConnectionType, char*, bool)' to 'void (*)(WebServer_My2&, WebServer_My2::ConnectionType, char*, bool)'
Web_HelloWorld:57: error: initializing argument 1 of 'void WebServer_My2::setDefaultCommand(void (*)(WebServer_My2&, WebServer_My2::ConnectionType, char*, bool))'
Web_HelloWorld:61: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(WebServer_My2KNJ&, WebServer_My2::ConnectionType, char*, bool)' to 'void (*)(WebServer_My2&, WebServer_My2::ConnectionType, char*, bool)'
Web_HelloWorld:61: error: initializing argument 2 of 'void WebServer_My2::addCommand(const char*, void (*)(WebServer_My2&, WebServer_My2::ConnectionType, char*, bool))'
```

The line `webserver.setDefaultCommand(&helloCmd);` in the file `Web_HelloWorld.ino` is highlighted at the time.

My Derived Class:

```
/*
  WebServer_My2KNJ.cpp - Extension of the library class 'WebServer_My2'
  Created by: COG008
  Date Created: 2013/10/17
*/

#ifndef WebServer_My2KNJ_h
#define WebServer_My2KNJ_h

#include <..\Webduino_My2\WebServer_My2.h>

class WebServer_My2KNJ: public WebServer_My2
{
public:

// constructor for webserver object
WebServer_My2KNJ(const char *p_urlPrefix = "", int p_port = 80); 
};
WebServer_My2KNJ::WebServer_My2KNJ(const char *p_urlPrefix, int p_port) : 
WebServer_My2::WebServer_My2(p_urlPrefix, p_port)
{
;
}

#endif
```

**Note:**

1. I am a Newbie to C++, so bear with me.
2. All files used except 'WebServer_My2KNJ.h' are basically the same found at 'https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino'.
3. 'Web_HelloWorld.ino' compiles and runs fine if I use 'WebServer_My2.h' instead of 'WebServer_My2KNJ.h'.
4. In the parent class 'WebServer_My2.h', all I did was to modify 'WebServer.h' by changing 'private:' to 'protected:', and the class name.
5. The reason I am going to this trouble, is that I want to later add more functionality to this class.  Hence to keep things cleaner and simpler, it is best I have my code in a derived class.

Comment: Did you change the `helloCmd()` parameters at all?

Comment: Nope, I did not make any changes to the 'helloCmd()' function.  As I  said earlier, if I #include 'WebServer_My2.h' instead of 'WebServer_My2KNJ.h', the Arduino app 'Web_HelloWorld.ino' compiles and works fine.  The non modified version of this app 'Web_HelloWorld.ino' can be view via the link given above ('https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino').

Comment: The problem is that the `helloCmd` which is getting passed to `setDefaultCommand()` doesn't quite match what it expects. If you didn't modify it then there must be something else affecting its parameters, e.g. a typedef somewhere. Where did WebServer_My2.h come from? Is it exactly the same as WebServer.h?

Comment: It came from the main file 'Webserver.h' found at the Webduino library(see the github link given above).  All I did as I said above is change the file and class name to 'WebServer_My2.h' and made the private properties 'protected'.  Note:  The app compiles and runs good when I #include this class instead: 'WebServer_My2.h'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Change `helloCmd()` to take a `WebServer_My2&` instead of a `WebServer_My2KNJ&`.

**Long answer:**

It looks like the problem stems from the `Command` function pointer typedef in your `WebServer_My2.h` file. It's presumably declared as follows (line ~169):

```
typedef void Command(WebServer_My2 &server, ConnectionType type,
                     char *url_tail, bool tail_complete);
```

That means it's a pointer to a function which accepts a reference to a `WebServer_My2` object as its first parameter (followed by some others). There are some methods, such as `setDefaultCommand()`, which accept function pointers of this exact type. C++ is strict here. You can't substitute another function pointer which accepts reference parameters of a derived type.

I know you said you didn't modify `helloCmd`, but based on the error message, I have to assume you actually changed the parameter list to this:

```
void helloCmd(WebServer_My2KNJ &server, WebServer_My2::ConnectionType type, char *, bool)
```

The problem therefore comes when the code tries to do these lines:

```
webserver.setDefaultCommand(&helloCmd);
webserver.addCommand("index.html", &helloCmd);
```

The `setDefaultCommand()` and `addCommand()` methods are expecting a function pointer which takes a `WebServer_My2` reference as its first parameter. However, `helloCmd()` actually takes a `WebServer_My2KNJ` reference. That won't work because the types are different (even though one is derived from the other).

A quick solution is to change `helloCmd()` as I suggested in the short answer above. That way it should at least be able to compile and run the example. If you want to use the extended functionality that you added to your subclass, then you can do this in the function:

```
WebServer_My2KNJ * myServer = dynamic_cast<WebServer_My2KNJ*>(&server);
if (myServer) {
    // myServer is safe to use here
}
```

You can then use the `myServer` pointer to access all your added webserver functionality. Just remember that it's a pointer though, so you need to use the `->` operator instead of the `.` operator to access members.

The `dynamic_cast` converts down the inheritance hierarchy if possible. It returns a null pointer (0) if the conversion doesn't work, which is why the `if ()` block is necessary.

Comment: Hi Peter:  Your hard; Top Notch etc.  I followed your short answer advice; created a WebServer_My2.cpp to go with the shortened 'WebServer_My2.h' and it worked once I included the class 'WebServer_My2.h' in the 'Web_HelloWorld.ino' application.  For example, the compiler was giving an error of undefined reference to `WebServer_My2::processConnection(char*, int*)' etc when if left out the additional include.